# HTML Video Reverse Play Laggy Especially on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Playing HTML videos in reverse can be accomplished with JavaScript, but I am having issues that all the methods I found are slightly laggy, and can't find a smooth reverse play.
On mobile devices it is even worse as the lag is amplified and the video skips rather than plays in reverse.

Similar topics:

[Play video on hover, play it on reverse on mouse off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483562/play-video-on-hover-play-it-on-reverse-on-mouse-off)

[Play video in reverse mouse move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66491010/play-video-in-reverse-mouse-move)

Is anyone else having the same issue? And how can we smoothen out the reverse play?

Code can be found in the linked topics.

thanks!

Comment: Videos, video codecs, and video acceleration are all optimized for forward play. You're lucky you get anything close to smooth when playing in reverse.

Comment: @Ouroborus Good to know. Thanks for your input. I guess I'll drop this approach for now, then.